# Use of unique_ptr and cudaMalloc

Tags: c++11, pointers, cuda, unique-ptr

I've been thinking about playing around with using std::unique_ptr with device pointers in CUDA. What I was wondering is if the current c++11 unique_ptr can be used in conjunction with cudaMalloc. I know it can be used with normal malloc ([Is it possible to use a C++ smart pointers together with C's malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477525/is-it-possible-to-use-a-c-smart-pointers-together-with-cs-malloc)), but cudaMalloc doesn't return the pointer in the function's return statement. Instead, it returns an error code. The pointer is returned in a reference.

This [blog post](https://ernestyalumni.wordpress.com/2017/09/28/bringing-cuda-into-the-year-2011-c11-smart-pointers-with-cuda-cub-nccl-streams-and-cuda-unified-memory-management-with-cub-and-cublas/) recommends the following technique:

```
auto deleter=[&](float* ptr){ cudaFree(ptr); };
std::unique_ptr<float[], decltype(deleter)> d_in(new float[size], deleter);
cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, size * sizeof(float));
```

**Question:** However, I'm concerned that this creates host memory that never gets deleted (i.e. `d_in(new float[size], deleter);`)?  Unless `new float[size]` doesn't actually generate host memory or is overridden? If the above doesn't in fact work, could defining my own cudaMalloc wrapper work? - to pass the pointer to unique_ptr?

Something like:

```
void* myCudaMalloc(size_t mySize){ 
    void * p; 
    checkCUDAerrorMacro(cudaMalloc((void**) &p, size);) 
    return p;
}

...

auto deleter=[](float* ptr){ cudaFree(ptr); };
std::unique_ptr<float[], decltype(deleter)> d_in(myCudaMalloc(size_t mySize), deleter);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some work I figured out how to test 3 versions of it - tl;dr the blog post's version (v1) does indeed leak, but can be tweaked so that it doesn't (v2) and improved (v3):

common code:

```
template <typename Deleter>
using unique_p = std::unique_ptr<float[], Deleter>;

constexpr int length = 20;
```

v1: (what is recommended in the blog post)

```
void version1(){
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted1\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in(new float[length],deleter);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, length * sizeof(float));

    ...
}
```

v2: (similar to above, but initializes d_in with nullptr)

```
void version2(){
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted2\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in(nullptr,deleter);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, length * sizeof(float));

    ...
}
```

v3: (d_in "adopts" pointer initialized with cudaMalloc)

```
void version3(){
    auto  myCudaMalloc = [](size_t mySize) { void* ptr; cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, mySize); return ptr; };
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted3\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in((float*)myCudaMalloc(length*sizeof(float)),deleter);

    ...
}
```

All 3 create proper device pointers. However, version 1 definitely leaks host memory (tested using valgrind with the cuda warnings suppressed: [Valgrind and CUDA: Are reported leaks real?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593450/valgrind-and-cuda-are-reported-leaks-real)). Neither v2 nor v3 leak host memory. cuda-memcheck also confirmed that there were no device-side memory leaks for any of the versions.

Between version 2 and 3, I prefer version 3 as it makes it more clear that unique_ptr owns the pointer and it follows the idiom of `new` and `malloc` in the unique_ptr constructor. You also only have to define the constructing function/lambda once and then can use it over and over again, so it is fewer lines of code.

========================

Full test code (compiled with nvcc -std=c++14):

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Deleter>
using unique_p = std::unique_ptr<float[], Deleter>;

__global__ void printArray(float * d_in, int num){
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){ printf("%f\t",d_in[i]); }
    printf("\n");

}

struct myDeleter{
    void operator()(float* ptr){ cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted\n"; } 
};

constexpr int length = 20;

void version1(){
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted1\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in(new float[length],deleter);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, length * sizeof(float));

    std::unique_ptr<float[]> h_out(new float[length]);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ h_out[i] = i; }

    cudaMemcpy(d_in.get(), h_out.get(),length*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    printArray<<<1,1>>>(d_in.get(),length);
}

void version2(){
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted2\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in(nullptr,deleter);
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, length * sizeof(float));

    std::unique_ptr<float[]> h_out(new float[length]);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ h_out[i] = i; }

    cudaMemcpy(d_in.get(), h_out.get(),length*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    printArray<<<1,1>>>(d_in.get(),length);
}


void version3(){
    auto  myCudaMalloc = [](size_t mySize) { void* ptr; cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, mySize); return ptr; };
    auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { cudaFree(ptr); std::cout<<"\nDeleted3\n"; };
    unique_p<decltype(deleter)> d_in((float*)myCudaMalloc(length*sizeof(float)),deleter);
    //unique_p<myDeleter> d_in((float*)myCudaMalloc(20*sizeof(float)));

    std::unique_ptr<float[]> h_out(new float[length]);
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){ h_out[i] = i; }

    cudaMemcpy(d_in.get(), h_out.get(),length*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    printArray<<<1,1>>>(d_in.get(),length);
}

int main(){

    version1();
    version2();
    version3();

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This pattern has worked for me pretty well:

```
int main(){
float* deviceArray_raw;
gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&deviceArray_raw, 100 * sizeof(float)));
auto deleter = [](float* ptr) { gpuErrchk(cudaFree(ptr)); };
std::unique_ptr<float[], decltype(deleter)> deviceArray(deviceArray_raw, deleter);
...
...
return 0;
}
```

Apart from host memory leaks, one also needs to be careful about device memory leaks.
Wrapping up cuda API calls in `gpuErrchk` helps with this. I was able to catch some weird behavior using this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this [git repo](https://github.com/roostaiyan/CudaSharedPtr). Both `fun::cuda::shared_ptr` and `fun::cuda::unique_ptr` have been implemented in this repository for `Cuda device pointers` based on `std::shared_ptr`. It also provides many other functions to work with Cuda device pointers in a straightforward manner, including:

```
bool create(size_t size);//! you can use create to allocate memory or simply upload your data without calling this function
void upload_async(const std::vector<T> &data_vec, cudaStream_t stream);
void upload(const std::vector<T> &data_vec);
void download_async(std::vector<T> &data_vec, cudaStream_t stream) const;
void download(std::vector<T> &data_vec) const;
void upload_async(const T* data_arr, int n_elements, cudaStream_t stream);
void upload(const T* data_arr, int n_elements);
void download_async(T* data_vec, cudaStream_t stream) const;
void download(T_ELEM* data_vec) const;
```

### Usage Example:

```
std::shared_ptr<T[]> data_host = std::shared_ptr<T[]>(new T[n]);
.
.
.

// In host code:
fun::cuda::shared_ptr<T> data_dev;
data_dev->upload(data_host.get(), n);
// In .cu file:
// data_dev.data() points to device memory which contains data_host;
```

This repository is indeed a single header file ([`cudasharedptr.h`](https://github.com/roostaiyan/CudaSharedPtr/blob/main/cudasharedptr.h)), so it will be easy to manipulate it if is necessary for your application.